# Only Generate Chart If PHP Variable Has Value

Tags: javascript, php, html, joomla, joomla3.5

I am using php & Charts.js to generate a chart of data based off an html `<select>`  My issue is that even if nothing is selected from the html `<select>` a blank chart is displayed at the bottom of the page as opposed to displaying the `echo` statement in my `else {}` block.

How should I re-write this syntax so that a chart is **ONLY** created IF a selection is made from the html `<select>`

```
<body>
    <form method="POST">
    <p>Select Sales Name:
            <select name="Name">
                <option value="">Select A Name...</option>
                <option value="Joe">Joe</option>
                <option value="Jack">Jack</option>
                <option value="Jerry">Jerry</option>
                <option value="Jimmy">Jimmy</option></select></p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Show Me">
    </form>
</body>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $whatsalesprsn = $_POST['Name'];
    if ($whatsalesprsn == "Joe") { $region = "East"; }
    if ($whatsalesprsn == "Jack") { $region = "West"; }
    if ($whatsalesprsn == "Jerry") { $region = "North"; }
    if ($whatsalesprsn == "Jimmy") { $region = "South"; }
    if (isset($region)) {
        $query = "Select * from salesdata where salesregion = '$region'";
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $rows = $db->loadColumn();
        $output = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        $column = $db->loadColumn($i);
        array_push($output, $column);
    }
    $data = json_encode($output[0]);
    } else { echo "PLease select a sales person to display data for."; }
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="width: 75%;">
            <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        </div><script>
            //JavaScript to generate chart
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if(!empty($whatsalesprsn)){...}` try this

Comment: @Mr.Developer - where do you propose I add this check into my current syntax?

Comment: After this `$whatsalesprsn = $_POST['Name'];`

Comment: @Mr.Developer - where would the close bracket for the if statement be placed?  I placed it after the select statement, and a blank chart is still presented.

Comment: After this `$data = json_encode($output[0]);` Let me know if it is working

Comment: Is that working ?

Comment: @Mr.Developer - yes that is working, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `if statement` with [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function. SO if `if statement` will check `$whatsalesprsn` variable if is empty or not by using [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function

```
if(!empty($whatsalesprsn)){
 $whatsalesprsn = $_POST['Name'];
    if ($whatsalesprsn == "Joe") { $region = "East"; }
    if ($whatsalesprsn == "Jack") { $region = "West"; }
    if ($whatsalesprsn == "Jerry") { $region = "North"; }
    if ($whatsalesprsn == "Jimmy") { $region = "South"; }
    if (isset($region)) {
        $query = "Select * from salesdata where salesregion = '$region'";
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $rows = $db->loadColumn();
        $output = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        $column = $db->loadColumn($i);
        array_push($output, $column);
    }
    $data = json_encode($output[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you must be calling `new Chart(...)`.  If you do that without passing in valid data then Chart.js will create an empty chart (since that's what you told it to do).

If you've not got valid data (i.e. nothing's chosen in the the `<select>` element), don't instantiate Chart.js.  Something like:

```
if (data.length) {
    new Chart(...);
}
```